# Given a submersion $\pi:M\to N$ and a curve $\alpha:(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)\to N$, find $\gamma:(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)\to M$

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I came across the following exercise:

> Let $\pi:M\to N$ a submersion and $\alpha$ a smooth curve on $N$ with $\alpha(0)=q$. Show that given $p\in\pi^{-1}(q)$ and $v\in T_p M$ such that $(d\pi)_p v=\alpha'(0)$, there exists a smooth curve $\gamma:(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)\to M$ with $\alpha=\pi\circ\gamma$, $\gamma(0)=p$ and $\gamma'(0)=v$.

The most natural way to approach this is using that a submersion has local sections.

Indeed, for $q=\pi(p)$ there exists an open neighborhood $U$ and $\sigma:U\to M$ smooth such that $\pi\circ\sigma=\mathrm{Id}|_U$ and $\sigma(q)=p$.

Then we define $\gamma:(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)\to M$ given by $\gamma=\sigma\circ\alpha$ (where $\alpha(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)\subset U$). This $\gamma$ satisfies $\alpha=\pi\circ\gamma$, $\gamma(0)=p$.

But $\gamma'(0)=(d\sigma)_q (d\pi)_p v$ and I don't know how to show that $$(d\sigma)_q (d\pi)_p v=v$$ (Which seems weird because it is the another order $(d\pi)_p (d\sigma)_q=\mathrm{id}_{T_q U}$, which is the identity).

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: So it feels like you're right. It feels like we're missing some condition that $(d\sigma)_q(d\pi)_p v = v$. Maybe there's some theorem or lemma about submersions that says we can find such a $\sigma$?

Comment: I think if you look at the local normal form of a submersion https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submersion_(mathematics)#Topological_manifold_submersions
you get the sense that you *can* find such a $\sigma$. So I think there must be something which explicitly states that. Basically you're picking a path starting at $p$ with a given velocity.
Like I would bet that you can find a section $\sigma$ with that property for any given tangent vector $v$.

Comment: Yeah I haven't got the abstract version yet, but you can make a toy example. I'll put it in an answer just because of the lack of space in comments.

Answer (score 1):

So I think you *should* be able to find a $\sigma$ with the added property that
$(d\sigma)_q(d\pi)_p v = \gamma'(0) = v$. Since submersions have local normal forms, just pretend that you're working with a submersion from $\mathbb{R}^M$ to $\mathbb{R}^N$ (with $M \geq N$) where $\pi(x_1, ..., x_M) = (x_1, ..., x_N)$. (Normal forms are nice in that way.) If you can prove what you want for this case, then you can build back up to your manifolds using charts and such.
For simplicity, you can even just consider the example

$\pi:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $\pi(x, y, z) = (x, y)$ and $\alpha(t) = (t, 2t)$ as a map from $(-\epsilon, \epsilon)$ into $\mathbb{R}^2$. We have $\alpha(0) = (0, 0) = q$. For any point $p = (0, 0, z)\in\pi^{-1}(q)$ and velocity vector $v = (0, 0, a)$ in $T_pM$ with $d\pi_p(v) = \alpha'(0)$, we would end up with the curve $\gamma(t) = (t, 2t, at + z)$ which would have $\gamma'(0) = (0, 0, a)$ and $\gamma(0) = 0, 0, z)$ as required.

I think you can generalize the ideas from this example to get your result. Hopefully that's helpful and gives some more intuition.

Comment: Great, I could do it for the projection $\pi:\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^n$, and the rest of the proof is submersion local form. Maybe in a while I'll post it the full answer, but your answer definitely was useful! Thanks

Comment: @AleTolcachier yeah there's a bit more work to do to rigorously turn that intuition into generality. I'm...OK with you doing that work after getting some intuition to get ya started ha. Good luck, and happy to help!